# How To Put UIPickerView Outside UIView when it's loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I already have the code to animate UIPickerView to act like iOS keyboard, but the problem is when it's loaded for the first time, the UIPickerView is already shows up. I want to hide it first outside UIView area, until UIButton tapped. so it will animate just like iOS keyboard.

here's the picture to illustrate what I mean :

[image]

how can it be done? thank you.

Comment: are you saying that the picker view is loaded after the application is launched but you want to laod it after you tapped on the view....

Comment: actually, I have 2 UIView and UIPickerView is under the second UIView. not the first one. and it has Push animation between them. what I need is when I go to second UIView, the UIPickerView is hiding. and when I tap the button (on second UIView) the UIPickerView will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the frame of `pickerView` accordingly while initiating.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 900, 200, 200)];
```

if you want `pickerView` to appear from bottom then increase the y co-ordinate and if you want `pickerView` to appear from right then increase the x co-ordinate value

if `pickerView` is on the `UIView` which is again on some `UIViewController` then set the `ClipsToBounds` to YES.

```
[yourView setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: I tried to use your code : _registerList = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 900, 200, 200)]; but still UIPickerView perfectly sit on its position. nothing's change. I also modify the value of X (100) and Y (900), but again nothing's change...

Comment: here's my UIPickerView on interface file : @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *registerList;

Comment: its in viewDidLoad, thats ok....then I think you must be changing the frame somewhere else in your code, try debugging it and check the frame of pickerView..

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your reply... But could you be more specific about 'changing the frame'? Should I add another UI component under UIPickerView and treated as frame? Thank you

Comment: No no.... frame is the property that every UI Component has... by 'changing the frame' I meant that you must be doing [registerList setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)] somewhere else in your code other that initialization...just check this thing

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i cant comment so answering from this I think you are already placed an UIpicker view in your view concept is same as @xman said. If you didnt place picker view place it

then in .h create property for picker view

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{ 
 IBOutlet UIPickerView *statepicker;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *statepickerview;
```

in .m first synthesize

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize statepickerview;
```

in viewdidLoad initially set frame of picker view out of view example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 statepickerview.frame = CGRectMake(-9, 506, 367, 263);
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

then in action call the frame to visible postion

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPress:(id)sender {

    statepickerview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 250,321, 260);


}
```

when you press button if it is not visible then try to change the co-ordinates

If this not works properly check this link create view and place the picker view inside the custom view and change the frame size of the view
[see this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwHIud_3LUw) surely it will help

Comment: Hi Yohan, thanks for your reply. I did what you said, but my problem is always in viewDidLoad. those value (-9, 506, 367, 263) seems to be ignored by compiler. UIPickerView always placed right on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: k k i edited the answer i shared an url check this video surely it will help

Comment: set delegate, datasource and numberof compnent all then do the above

Comment: I saw that YouTube video, but something I can't see there... do I have to import something in my .h / .m in order to make CGRectMake works? because I did exactly what video said, but still UIView (container) is not moving anywhere...

Comment: no you don want to import anything i did the concept before some days it is worked. Have you kept the picker view in separate custom view

Comment: I did... I will give an update for this problem in new post, because I found something weird with my Xcode.. hold on... I need to screenshot my mac...

Comment: I put into simple Xcode project and it's not working, I know it sounds crazy, but it really happen... here's what I have : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850871/cgrectmake-is-not-working-with-uiview

Comment: answer this questions so only i can solve have you add delegate and datasource for picker view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37528/discussion-between-yohan-and-robert-hanson)

Answer (score 0):

You can set pickerview's y position with your window's height. Like this :

```
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
   pickerView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, appDelegate.window.frame.size.height,pickerView.frame.size.width,pickerView.frame.size.height)
```

You have to add pickerview in your view and then set frame of it.

Comment: I got this error : Use of undeclared identifier 'appDelegate'

Comment: @RobertHanson You need to get the reference to the delegate, e.g. ```id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];``` first.

Comment: @flashfabrixx : you are right, Robert, you have to make your delegate object then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer... case closed... it's all because of 'AutoLayout' is enabled on my XCode Project... when it's disabled, everything works as I expected.